# How to remove duplicates from list C#

Tags: c#, string, linq, list, duplicates

I want get same result as got with this code to remove duplicates for text document:

```
 File.WriteAllLines(@"doc.txt", lines.Select(line1 => line1.Trim()).Distinct().ToArray());
```

Same for list with large content after loading into the list or on the stage of loading but not from processed file:

```
List<string> contentList = new List<string>();
```

to read content I use it this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < contentList.Count; i++)
{                        
     textBox8.AppendText(contentList[i] + "\n");                        
}
```

and on the loading stage also inside the loop string by string:

```
contentList.Add(inputStr);
```

Desired result is avoid duplicates if I got duplicates inside:

```
one
two
three
four
two
five
six
three
```

desired result should be:

```
one
two
three
four    
five
six
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have list of strings you can use [Distinct()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx) method of LINQ.

```
var result = contentList.Distinct();
```

If you have list of objects then you will need to implement custom equality comparer which will lets you to apply custom distinct rule.

Please make sure you included `System.Linq` namespace.

Comment: exactly very useful